# UIWebView throwing Frame load interrupted error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am working on application in which I am downloading file and saving it in documents directory 
so when user uses the application next time he can directly open the file which are already downloaded

I am showing that file on next screen in `UIWebView` using follwing code :

```
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.url]; // where url is url of file in documents directory
[webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

This is working perfectly for file having extension **pdf**  but there are some files with extension **asp** and 
 when I am trying to open those file I get this error 
 Error

> Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=102 "Frame load interrupted"
>   UserInfo=0x9b58fa0
>   {NSErrorFailingURLKey=file:///Users/poonam/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.1/Applications/7EE726E5-5315-4BEE-9629-F85FBCD46BC3/Documents/V2_076eb8847184be9e441f1bed7cc1a705.asp,
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=file:///Users/poonam/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.1/Applications/7EE726E5-5315-4BEE-9629-F85FBCD46BC3/Documents/V2_076eb8847184be9e441f1bed7cc1a705.asp,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Frame load interrupted}

To solve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23473780/ios-uiwebview-frame-load-interrupted) I tried

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
   if ([url.scheme isEqualToString:@"file"]) {
    NSLog(@"Open start page");
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    return NO;
}
return YES;
}
```

But However I am not able to solve my problem. Any suggestions please

Comment: May be help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275695/uiwebview-and-iphone-content-does-not-postback-asp-net-browser-capability-issue

Comment: Did you do this on the simulator or an actual device? I had the same issue on the sim but it worked on a device.

Answer (score 1):

Finally after spending hours on this , Here i found the solution for this common Webview "frame load interrupted" issue:

- Download the file in bytes form
- Store it in the Local Storage
- Load the file in Web view with the local path and it works

Code for the above steps:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59194408/12483992

Comment: I have a POST request to the server which responds with the PDF data. The fileName with .pdf extension is sent as parameter in application/x-www-form-urlencoded format. I'm getting Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=102 “Frame load interrupted” error as well. How to solve it? Please help. TIA

Comment: are you still facing the issue ?

Answer (score -1):

Late answer but this could be useful for someone.
I got this same error and it was because I didn't realize I was returnint false in

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool
```

in my UIWebView Delegate. Changed to

```
return true
```

fixed the issue and

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)
```

was called after that.