# How to open URL in WebView in iOS?

Tags: ios, url, uiwebview, nsurl

I have tried to open below url in WebView

http://1-dot-smartrefill-968.appspot.com/#/#mfucci@gmail_com

But unable to make object of `NSURL`.

Comment: in which language u tried this in objective C or swift add language tag and show your tried code

Comment: NSString *strUrl = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",ITEM_URL,[AppDelegate_.usermanager userName]] stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLPathAllowedCharacterSet]];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strUrl]];
        [self.webView loadRequest:request];

Comment: #define ITEM_URL @"http://1-dot-smartrefill-968.appspot.com/#/#"

Comment: what the output you get here `strUrl`

Answer (score 2):

where's your code?
did u use a webView?

I used this method :

```
[_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

Comment: I have tried all this,then post this question. NSURL is not create, it's null with that url.

Answer (score 1):

**Step-1**

> initially add `NSAppTransportSecurity` in your .plist, see [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33295660/cannot-open-url-in-uiwebview-in-ios-9-0)

**step-2**

> call the url like

```
NSString *urlAddress =  @"http://1-dot-smartrefill-968.appspot.com/#/#mfucci@gmail_com"; 
[self.yourwebviewName loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSURL URLWithString:[urlAddress stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]]]];
```

Comment: NSString *strUrl = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",ITEM_URL,[AppDelegate_.usermanager userName]] stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLPathAllowedCharacterSet]];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strUrl]];
        [self.webView loadRequest:request];

Comment: @AshokD - in this place `[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",ITEM_URL,[AppDelegate_.usermanager userName]] stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharac‌​terSet URLPathAllowedCharacterSet]];` try my ansswer once

Answer (score 1):

Try to encode your `URL` using `addingPercentEncoding` instead of `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` because it is deprecated.

**In Swift:**

- **For Swift 3**:

  ```
  let strUrl = "http://1-dot-smartrefill-968.appspot.com/#/#mfucci@gmail_com"
  let encodedUrl = strUrl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
  ```
- **For Swift 2.3 or lower**:

  ```
   let encodedUrl = strUrl.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())
  ```

**In Objective-C**

```
NSString *strUrl = @"http://1-dot-smartrefill-968.appspot.com/#/#mfucci@gmail_com";
NSString *encodedUrl = [strUrl stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: This url is not load webview, that is an error. Can pls suggest ?

Comment: @AshokD Have you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19713610/how-to-resolve-frame-load-interrupted-error-in-uiwebview and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23473780/ios-uiwebview-frame-load-interrupted

Answer (score 0):

For **swift** :

```
var url : NSString = "http://1-dot-smartrefill-968.appspot.com/#/#mfucci@gmail_com" 
var urlStr : NSString = url.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)! 
var searchURL : NSURL = NSURL(string: urlStr)! 
    webviewInstance.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: searchURL))
```

For **objective-c**

```
[webviewInstance loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSURL URLWithString:[your_URL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]]]];
```

Comment: I have tried all this,then post this question. NSURL is not create, it's null with that url.

Comment: have you done `NSUTF8StringEncoding` with your url string?

Comment: Yes, I have tried. But webview is not load that url.

Comment: RootViewController.m-->-[RootViewController webView:didFailLoadWithError:]@114: URL Error Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=102 "Frame load interrupted" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=file://http%253A%252F%252F1-dot-smartrefill-968.appspot.com%252F%2523%252F%2523himen%2540blupixeltech.in, NSLocalizedDescription=Frame load interrupted, NSErrorFailingURLKey=file://http%253A%252F%252F1-dot-smartrefill-968.appspot.com%252F%2523%252F%2523himen%2540ashok.in}